# Sonar - CSharp Plugins Ecosystem - Can not execute Sonar: Error while trying to get the next element name

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar CSharp Plugins Ecosystem is throwing error at the end of processing.
I have checked the coverage-report.xml and it only include one line.

```
<PartCoverReport version="4.0" date="2011-08-10T10:09:12.1721003+08:00" />
```

I think this is the possible reason for the error.
How can I fix this issue? Is this a configuration issue?
Thanks in advance.

Please see piece of error message below:
...

```
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.fxcop.FxCopSensor@e6529c...  
[INFO]  Microsoft (R) FxCop Command-Line Tool, Version 10.0 (10.0.30319.1) X86  
[INFO]  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, All Rights Reserved.  
[INFO]    
[INFO]  Loading C:\JanusPilot\SonarDotnetExample\Example.Application\target\sonar  \sonar.FxCop...    
[INFO]  Loaded DesignRules.dll...  
[INFO]  Loaded GlobalizationRules.dll...  
[INFO]  Loaded NamingRules.dll...  
[INFO]  Loaded PerformanceRules.dll...  
[INFO]  Loaded Example.Application.exe...  
[INFO]  Initializing Introspection engine...  
[INFO]  Analyzing...  
[INFO]  Analysis Complete.  
[INFO]  Writing 1 messages...  
[INFO]  Writing report to C:\JanusPilot\SonarDotnetExample\Example.Application\t  
arget\sonar\fxcop-report.xml...  
[INFO]  Done:00:00:01.1050632  
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.fxcop.FxCopSensor@e6529c done: 2342 ms  
[INFO]  Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gallio.CoverageReportSensor@eb73e...  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Total time: 1:14.037s   
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 10 10:13:29 CST 2011  
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-2:s  
onar (default-cli) on project example: Can not execute Sonar: Error while trying  
 to get the next element name: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,75]  
[ERROR] Message: Can not call 'getLocalName(): cursor does not point to a valid  
node (curr event [null]; cursor state CLOSED)  
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit  
ch.  
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea  
d the following articles:  
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the developpers of the C# plugins.
You should rather ask for help by sending a mail to the sonar user mailing list.
Your partcover reports shows that partcover did not succeed to gather coverage measures suring test execution.
You have 3 solutions :

- try ncover3
- skip coverage

If you need more details, again, please drop a message to the user mailing list

Regards

Comment: I have tried the ncover3 and it works. My local workstation is windows7(64-bit). I think the partcover not fully supporting the windows7(64-bit). Thanks for your answer.